# How does an open source project get advertised with Open Source Advertising from Stackexchange?

Tags: support, open-source-advertising

How does an open source project get advertised with Open Source Advertising from Stackexchange?

Here you can add an answer as an advertisement and then it needs to get (n) votes to get advertised.

What is that (n) number and if it gets many answers with more than the (n) votes how is the advertisements then choosed? Obviously the ones with more votes is choosed but what happens if there are many with the same number of votes and what is the maximum number of answers to be choosed?

Comment: @Servy Not everything I'm looking for is there

Comment: Yes it is...  Perhaps you should read through it again.

Comment: @LightningBoltϟ: Perhaps you should explain what is it exactly that you're looking for that's not covered in Servy's link?

Comment: (n) is currently 6 i.e. answer with net score of 6 or more will be eligible for display. There is special mechanism that "rotate" those ads and choose one at random, it can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/ossads/220x250). Many answers don't really matter, only one is chosen at any given moment. There is no limit, there can be even 1000 (in theory). You can see all eligible ads with some stats for each [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/210389).